# Difference between AMI created from a snapshot and ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot, amazon-ami

What is the difference in the `AMI` created from a `EC2 snapshot` and the `AMI` created directly from a running `EC2 instance`?

Comment: did you look http://serverfault.com/questions/578360/creating-an-ec2-ami-image-from-a-running-instance-vs-from-a-volume-snapshot

Comment: There is no difference. If you create an AMI from a running instance it automatically takes a snapshot, then creates an AMI from that snapshot.